# C puts() without newline

Tags: c, file, newline, puts

I currently have this program that prints a text file on the console, but every line has an extra new line below it.
if the text was

hello
world

it would output
hello

world

the code is this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    FILE* fp;
    char input[80], ch = 'a';
    char key[] = "exit\n";
    int q;

    fp = fopen("c:\\users\\kostas\\desktop\\original.txt", "r+");

    while (!feof(fp)) {
        fgets(input, 80, fp);
        puts(input);
    }
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Isn't `iostream` a C++ -only library and `using` a C++ -only keyword?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`puts()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/functions/puts.html) adds the newline character by the library specification. You can use `printf` instead, where you can control what gets printed with a format string:

```
printf("%s", input);
```

Comment: That "%s" instead of just using "printf(input);" is critical, lest any percent signs in input crash your program.

Comment: calling printf with "%s" is less efficient than fputs, but you probably don't care

Comment: @portforwardpodcast Compiler do change printf("%s",sting) to fputs(string,stdout), when you enalbe optimization, at least gcc does this. Some compiler maybe change it to fwrite() which is faster when you know the string lenght.

Comment: Why not just use the answer below?

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 when did it do that? I don't see this transformation being done with any version of GCC I have available.
I think the main issue is getting the stdout at the point of optimization.

Comment: @DanM. You are correct, my example was wrong, but in case when you have `"%s\n"` as format string gcc will replace it with `puts()`. Try to compile `main(){printf("%s\n","");}` with `gcc <input file>`.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 but this question is about no newline specifically ;P

Answer (score 93):

Typically one would use fputs() instead of puts() to omit the newline.  In your code, the

```
puts(input);
```

would become:

```
fputs(input, stdout);
```

Comment: You could use printf() as well, but with a small amount of added overhead :-)

Comment: I'm glad I found this answer, as I didn't want to have the overhead of `printf`

Comment: In fact, `printf("%s", s)` have no overhead over `fputs(input, stdout)`, but `fputs` looks clean.

Comment: The `printf("%s", s)` has to parse the format string, which is definitely less overhead than a system call - but have you *seen* the code for parsing the format string?  That's definitely overhead.   q.v. https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/stdio-common/vfprintf-internal.c.html

Comment: @AlexNorth-Keys if you printf with newline, gcc will turn it into puts. https://godbolt.org/z/784dEvnjP

Comment: Well, wait long enough and gcc might turn it into some more efficient quantum computed thing.  Compiler magic marches on, although this often impedes debugging.

Comment: But it won't when using `printf("%s", ...)` without a newline, which was the original question: https://godbolt.org/z/h4jWeobY6

So `fputs(s, stdout)` really is the right answer here over `printf("%s", s)`.

Answer (score 5):

You can also write a custom *puts* function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int my_puts(char const s[static 1]) {
    for (size_t i = 0; s[i]; ++i)
        if (putchar(s[i]) == EOF) return EOF;

    return 0;
}

int main() {
    my_puts("testing ");
    my_puts("C puts() without ");
    my_puts("newline");

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
testing C puts() without newline
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
void put_s(char* s){
    while(*s) putchar(*s++);
}
```

Just for the sakes of having more examples, here is another one involving recursion:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
void put_s(char* s){
    if(!*s) return;
    putchar(*s);
    put_s(s+1);
}
```

Note: I noticed that your code wouldn't compile, because of the `#include<iostream>` and the `using namespace std;`.

Comment: It works but could be quite inefficient if stdout is not buffered.